# How to implement google map API in C# Application?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I want to implement Google map API in my project.I have searched alot on internet but still i m not able to integrate it in my application. Any one help me how can i implement it in my application. Thanks in advance

Comment: google knows: http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/171162

Answer (score 1):

CodePlex project : Use [Google Maps API for .net](http://gmaps.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some wrapper http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/csharp-google-static-map.aspx but I really think that it is better to do this in the Api native language (Javascript) and simply follow the documentation.